# Spark Java - how to convert a non delimited file into dataset in spark java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read a non delimited file and convert it into dataset in spark java. Need to map to column names by reading from csv and splitting each line based on size of each attribute. Please suggest me how to do in spark java.

Comment: Gives you the right idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot do that in Java as I use Scala, but one can `FoldLeft` applying successive `substring` or `slice` operations, or do that also without `FoldLeft`.

An example in Scala which you can convert - this is the less advanced option:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// Cols for renaming.
val list = List("C1", "C2", "C3")

// Gen some data.
val df = Seq(
       ("C1111sometext999"),
       ("C2222sometext888"),
       ).toDF("data")

// "heavy" lifting.  
val df2 = df.selectExpr("substring(data, 0, 5)", "substring(data, 6,8)", "substring(data, 14,3)")

// Rename from list. Can also do "as Cn" in selectExpr. 
val df3 = df2.toDF(list:_*) 
df3.show
```

returns:

```
+-----+--------+---+
|   C1|      C2| C3|
+-----+--------+---+
|C1111|sometext|999|
|C2222|sometext|888|
+-----+--------+---+
```

You will then have to convert to types.